# CSS3 Multiple Columns cut off italic text

Tags: css, webkit, multiple-columns, italic

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/zzhT3/ (look at letter "p", please),

Unfortunately, when I use multiple-columns, webkit cuts characters written with italic font (if they go beyond of the boundaries of the column). Is this normal? Or is it possible to fix it? Thanks.

**Html:**

```
<div>
pony pony pony pony...
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
div{    
    -webkit-column-width: 48px; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px; 
    font-style: italic;  
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/18319/parts-of-italicscript-text-being-cut-off-at-start-of-line/p1

This is obviously a problem with css in itself. I wonder if any of the Google Open Web Fonts would do this, seeing as they're all web optimized.

Therefore you may want to consider using a multiple column div layout (divs inside of a div) instead of using `-webkit` rules. They're cross-browser, and I think divs are more flexible in terms of what you can do with them.

Comment: Floating/inlining divs is not even close to the same thing as using the Multi-column module.

Comment: I suggested an alternative. I did not say they were similar.